# Liquid Nitrogen Tank Keeps Venting

Tags: pressure, temperature

I have an industrial laser cutting machine, which uses liquid nitrogen. Liquid nitrogen is always boiling and the tank periodically vents excess pressure. The tank is at 350PSI. I have been told that lowering the pressure to 200 PSI will change the boiling point and reduce venting. Is this correct?

From a business stand point, venting the tank to reduce the pressure is exactly what I am trying to avoid in the first place - that is, losing nitrogen to the atmosphere.

Would chilling the exterior of the tank solve my problem?

Comment: It sounds as thoiugh your tank has an insulation problem. Have you contacted your LN2  supplier for advice?

Comment: Some venting is normal in some situations. We have a big LN2 tank here for a laser as well. As long as the Machine is used it rarely vents. But if the machine is down (during holidays) it starts to vent from time to time (the forst time after a few days than maybe twice during a workday). If it's more often either the pressurisation system is leaky or the insulation is not good enough...

Comment: Hi Mike Stone and Kruemi -

Thank you for your replies. Following your advice, going forward we will insulate/chill the tank. We have no control of the quality of the tank's insulation from our LN2 supplier. And there is a distinct possibility that we will receive the same crummy tank over and over. Better to chill/insulate on our own. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

> Liquid nitrogen is always boiling

Unless the system has active refrigeration, boiling would be expected.  Just the better the insulation, the slower the rate.  A 47 liter laboratory dewar might have an evaporation rate (when undamaged) of around half a liter per day.  But loss of vacuum, insulation damage, etc. will increase the rate (sometimes dramatically)

> I have been told that lowering the pressure to 200 PSI will change the boiling point

Yes, it will lower the boiling point.  The fluid in the tank reach a colder equilibrium temperature.

> ... and reduce venting.

Don't see how it could.  The fluid will boil to remove any heat that enters.  By lowering the boiling point, this would increase the temperature difference between inside and outside, and that will increase the heat flow.  Greater heat flow, greater boiling to remove the heat, greater loss of liquid.

> Would chilling the exterior of the tank solve my problem?

Anything that reduces heat transfer into the liquid will help.  But if there's a problem with the tank or the insulation, it's unlikely that chilling the outside would be an economical solution.